# SQLCE DLL does not affect table

Tags: c#, sql

Hi I want to add column to my .sdf database, but method ExecuteNonQuery() return -1 and database does not change.
When I try to execute the sql command in SSMS everything works fine.

this is my code:

```
private int ExecuteSql(string sql)
    {
        int result;

        using(var ceCon = new SqlCeConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            if(ceCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                ceCon.Open();

            using(var ceCommand = new SqlCeCommand(sql, ceCon))
            {
                try
                {
                    result = ceCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                } catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                } finally
                {
                    ceCon.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

and this is my sql command : `ALTER TABLE Dictionary ADD TestDicProp int NULL;`

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why will you want to do `ALTER` from c# instead of DB?

Comment: I want to automatize process. I have another source and when I add column to that one I want to automaticaly add column to DB.

Comment: The logins you use are the same in SSMS and your program?

Comment: @stickybit : as a connection string I use just file path to .sdf file becouse its local. I am able to select data from DB but not to do DDL